# Smoothing a shapefile output - Basemap python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I'm working with a shapefile. I have no issues whatsoever reading it in, plotting it, and making the map pretty-looking. However, when I plot it (after reprojecting it to the correct EPSG using QGIS), the edges are all jagged (as shown below). Is there a way to smooth it using Python?[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

#insert code for basemap setup m = Basemap(...)
m.arcgisimage(service = 'ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D', xpixels = 1000, verbose = True)
states_info = m.readshapefile('shapefiles/states', 'states')
spc_info = m.readshapefile('shapefiles/corrected_epsg', 'spc', drawbounds = False)

patches = []
ax = plt.gca()

for info, shape in zip(m.spc_info, m.spc):
    x, y = zip(*shape)
    if info['DN'] == 2: 
        color = '#80c580'
        zorder = 2
        patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True))
    if info['DN'] == 5: 
        color = '#f7f780'
        zorder = 3
        patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True))
    ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= color, zorder=zorder, alpha = 0.7))
```

[Source](http://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/day1otlk.html) for these shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9555/free-tool-to-simplify-parcel-shapefiles)'s answers explain how the Shapely Package has a Simplify method based on the Douglas-Puecker algorithm.